# How to return the previous month using R?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

So in R I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Month1
December
October
April
February
January
```

All I want is to return the previous month.

Is there a function for this? Perhaps in lubridate? This is what I want in the end:

```
Month1     Month2
December   November
October    September
April      March
February   January
January    December
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be:

```
c('December', 'November', 'September') -> x   

library(lubridate)
months(dym(paste0('01-2020-', x)) - 1)
#"November" "October"  "August"
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R has `month.name` which contains the names of all the months.

Use the modulo operator to handle December mapping to January.

```
m <- c('December', 'October', 'April', 'February', 'January')

month.name[(match(m, month.name) - 2) %% 12 + 1]
#> [1] "November"  "September" "March"     "January"   "December"
```

Comment: Hi I'm looking for a tidyverse solution